# PostgreSQL, about FORCE NOT NULL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv

I have an issue using `FORCE NOT NULL` in PostgreSQL.

I have a table with 10 columns and I need to load data to it from a CSV file.

I'm using the following query, which works perfectly:

```
COPY "myschema"."mytable" 
FROM '/var/www/myapp/myfile.csv' 
DELIMITERS '|' 
CSV 
FORCE NOT NULL 
attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5, attr6, attr7, attr8, attr9, attr10;
```

I need to know how to do this without explicitly coping all the columns as arguments to the `FORCE NOT NULL` because I have more tables with hundreds of columns that require this.

I tried `FORCE NOT NULL *`, `FORCE NOT NULL *` but the query returns an error. I can't find a solution to this on the Internet.

Thanks in advance for the help you can provide me!

Comment: You forgot to mention your version of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

`FORCE NOT NULL *` is not valid postgresql. A patch for this was almost passed but rejected.
Read this [mailing list](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/COPY-WITH-CSV-FORCE-QUOTE-td2012428.html) for the discussion.

Comment: I read the mailing list. It's seem not to be solution for what i need to do. Thanks for the help. =(